# Append a template of html with javascript many times with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append this piece of code into my main html file many times (as I understand that is possible with Jquery). But my main problem is that I also have to modify some 'id' of the elements inside the html template based on the append number. For example, the first time I append the template, the id should be "item1", but the second time it should be "item2". In the template the ids I want to modify are: 
Sensor1
mac1
LastUpdate1
TempPlot1

Template:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 100px">
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <h2 id="Sensor1">Sensor desconectado!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: white;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-mb-3" style="text-align: center; ">
        <canvas id="gauge1" style="padding-top: 2%; margin-right: 50px; min-width: 200px;"></canvas> 
        <div class="card-body" style="text-align:left;">
          <div class="container" style="margin-left: -30px;">     
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>MAC</td>
                  <td id="mac1">xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>LastUpdate</td>
                  <td id="LastUpdate1">----------</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <span class="badge badge-success" style="display: none; " id="cnt1" >Conectado</span>
            <span class="badge badge-danger" style="display: block; " id="dcnt1">Desconectado</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-mb-9" style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="TempPlot1" style=" margin: auto; box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="modal bs-wifi1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="modal-header"><h4>WiFi INFO <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></h4></div>
      <div class="modal-body"><p><strong>WiFi:</strong><span id="wifi1">{REDWiFI}</span></p></div>
      <div class="modal-body"><p><strong>RSSI:</strong><span id="rssi1">{RSSI}</span></p></div>
      <div class="modal-body"><p><strong>AP:</strong><span id="ap1" data-toggle="cerrar_sesion" title="Ingrese la direccion IP en su navegador para obtener mas informacion y poder configurar una nueva red WiFi.. Recuerde conectarse al mismo WiFI que figura arriba!"  data-placement="bottom" >{IP}</span></p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><h4>Cerrar Sesion <i class="fa fa-lock"></i></h4></div>
      <div class="modal-body"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Estas seguro que queres cerrar sesion?</div>
      <div class="modal-footer"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Cerrar Sesion</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would it be possible to put the template in a separate file? or has to be inside js.
Thanks.

Comment: how many times you want to repeat?

Comment: It should depend on a variable, I understand you should do a for loop. In some cases only twice, in other cases up to 10, That's why I wanted to do it dynamically.

Comment: intention of doing this??

Comment: I am creating a little dashboard for a IOT project (Internet of the things), every device is going to have a different number of sensors, so I need to add this template( gauge, chart and some extra info) depending on the number of sensors I have. Im planning to change the id to be able to then put the data of that specific sensor. To be honest, I am not sure if it is the best way, nor the simplest since it is my first website and I am new with this type of programming nut I think this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **for loop** and **template literals** to insert id dynamically

This is a basic example which creates 10 spans with different ids

```js
for(let i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
  let div=document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML=`<span id="span${i}">Hey this is Span ${i} </span>`;
  document.body.append(div);
}
```